# How to add new rows for the missing indexes in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this

```
0     204,255,204
1     204,255,204
3     204,255,204
4     204,255,204
5         0,153,0
8     204,255,204
10    204,255,204
```

For every index that is missing from `[0,1,2....,13]` I want to add rows with the value `255,255,255` with the respective index

My final output would look like this:

```
    0     204,255,204
    1     204,255,204
    3     204,255,204
    4     204,255,204
    5         0,153,0
    8     204,255,204
    10    204,255,204
    2     255,255,255
    6     255,255,255
    7     255,255,255
    9     255,255,255
    11    255,255,255
    12    255,255,255
    13    255,255,255
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this ?

**UPDATE**
The `column` is a `categorical` one

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) setting `fill_value` to the specified value:

```
n = 13
df['col'].reindex(range(n+1), fill_value= '255,255,255')

0     204,255,204
1     204,255,204
2     255,255,255
3     204,255,204
4     204,255,204
5         0,153,0
6     255,255,255
7     255,255,255
8     204,255,204
9     255,255,255
10    204,255,204
11    255,255,255
12    255,255,255
13    255,255,255
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: 'fill_value' ('255,255,255') is not in this Categorical's categories.` Sorry I forgot to mention that the column is a categorical one. Can you think of any work around ?

Comment: Why categorical? It doesn't really seem suited for this. Start with `df['col'].astype(str)...` @quant

Answer (score 5):

1. Create missing indices
2. Create new df
3. Concat

```
add_indices = pd.Index(range(14)).difference(df.index)

add_df = pd.DataFrame(index=add_indices, columns=df.columns).fillna(255)

pd.concat([df, add_df])
```